# Binding #items of a MenuItem to visibility in a CompositeCollection

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatrigger

I have a `MenuItem` that is populated via an `ObservableCollection` plus one static `MenuItem` that i want to display only if the collection is empty.

To do that i am using `CompositeCollection`, and try to trigger the visibility of the `MenuItem` via `DataTrigger` but to no avail.

No matter if i use `HasItems` or `Items.Count`, the binding itself seems to be the problem:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="ClientsList" Header="Clients">
    <MenuItem.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={x:Static win32:ClientProcessHandler.ClientProcessList}}" />
            <MenuItem Header="No Client.." IsEnabled="False">
                <MenuItem.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <!-- Here is the binding -->
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=ClientsList}" Value="2">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.Style>
            </MenuItem>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </MenuItem.ItemsSource>
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path}" />
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.SelectClient, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding }" />
            <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnClick" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the `Count` property of the source collection:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Count, 
    Source={x:Static win32:ClientProcessHandler.ClientProcessList}}" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</DataTrigger>
```